# How do I fopen files I included in the apk?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, fopen, sdl-2

I wrote a small test application that uses SDL2 on Android via the NDK. It compiles and runs. However, as soon as I try to open files I get FileNotFound Exceptions. I added an assets Directory in my eclipse workdir and put files inside it. When I Export the projekt to an .apk, I can open the file in 7z and see that there is an assets Directory with those files in it. However, when the code gets executed and I try to open assets/somefile.txt, I get a FileNotFound Exception.

Google so far told me that I could put an sdcard in my device with those files on it and access it through /sdcard/ . I'ld like to include those files in my apk though.

How do I Access the files I put in assets ? Or where should I put those files and how should I adjust my path it can Access them at runtime?

Comment: It's not a duplicate of the one mvp suggested as that questions relates to Java/SDK and mine to C(++)/NDK.

Comment: Indeed it is not, but it is a duplicate of the NDK question.  Fundamentally, apk contents are not file system files, so your choices are basically using the assets api or parsing the .apk zip structure yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Place this code before anything else in your main activity ->

```
 if (Environment.getExternalStorageState (). equals (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
 File directory = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory () + + File.separator    "YourFolderName");
 directory.mkdirs ();

   }
```

Give this permission in the Manifest xml ->

```
  <uses-permission android: name = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: What exactly does this do? Does it extract the files from the apk to the external storage?

Comment: This is the first step. Makes you create a directory so that the user instalae your application on the device. Now, you put the files into sdcard / yourfolder. You have to explain what kind of performance will make your app. How do you want to open this file. For you open an image, for example, need a Image view Text view and to open a TXT text.

Comment: This does not answer the question which was asked.